# Installing R 4.1 from source on newly installed Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: r, installation

I tried to install R 4.1 on a newly set-up Ubuntu 20.04. After some struggle with the repositories and keys, I chose to install from source.

Visited https://www.r-project.org/ to download latest version of R. Ran **./configure** multiple times to note the requirement of various libraries which you may note as follows. ***I am hoping this will save significant amount of time for anyone intending to build from source.*** Suggestions welcome for speeding up the process or better solution. However my intention is to share entire set of libraries that I had to install on a naked installation of 20.04 on which the very first package I tried to install was R 4.1 (from source).

Directory where you downloaded the tar.gz (e.g. R-4.1.2.tar.gz in my case)

```
cd Downloads
```

Untar

```
tar -xvzf R-4.1.2.tar.gz
```

Enter directory

```
cd R-4.1.2
```

As root

```
sudo su
```

Try validating configuration (encountered many errors throughout and following libraries were installed)

```
./configure
```

Installed various libraries:

```
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install gfortran
apt-get install fort77
apt-get install libreadline-dev
apt-get install xorg-dev
apt-get install liblzma-dev libblas-dev
apt-get install gcc-multilib
apt-get install libbz2-dev
apt-get install libpcre2-dev
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
apt install default-jdk
make
make install
```

The above set worked for me and I am hopeful it may be of help.